# Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax not work with firefox 3.5.5

Tags: css, firefox, viewport

i use CSS  ( width: 17vw; height:17vw;)
it work for most browsers. but not work on firefox V3.5.5 
any suggestion

Comment: Use something else. Search for a polyfill?

Answer (score 4):

Viewport units have only been supported in firefox since version 19. Firefox 3.5 usage is at *%0.02* globally, so it is probably not worth supporting anyway. That means 1 out of every 5000 people are using it.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: thanks Steve
But :( my client test my code at that version , can i defined a special class run on firefox V3.5.5

Comment: You could user modernizr to apply different CSS to browsers that do not support viewport units. http://modernizr.com/